# Basic jQuery Price Calculator Promo Code Hack

Tags: jquery, calculator

I have a basic price calculator on a page and now need to add a (very basic and non-secure) "promo code" field to discount the total.

My HTML fields that matter:

```
<input type="text" id="Amount" /> <!-- the price amount field that gets updated via JS -->

<input type="text" id="promocode" /> <!-- promo code field -->

<input type="button" id="promoupdate" value="Update Price" /> <!-- button to click to update the Amount field -->

<select id="CAT_Custom_358914"> <!-- number of *additional* attendees to be paid for -->
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Note that there is always one default attendee, so choosing any number from the select field simply adds the number to 1. If I choose "3" from the select field, it means I have 4 total attendees.

Now, my Amount calculator currently adds up the registration options for each attendee. It works great:

```
$('.calculator').change(function() {
   var total = 0;

   $('.calculator option:selected').each(function() {
      var m = /\[\$(\d+\.\d+)\]/.exec(this.value);

      if(m !== null) {
         total += +m[1];
      }
   });

   var decimalPart = (total - Math.floor(total)) * 100;

   $('#Amount').val(Math.floor(total) + '.' + (decimalPart < 10 ? '0' : '') + decimalPart);
});
```

You don't really need to know what each ".calculator" field looks like, but in case you're curious:

```
<select name="CAT_Custom_359359" id="CAT_Custom_359359" class="cat_dropdown calculator">
    <option value=" ">-- Please select --</option>
    <option value="Friday and Saturday [$225.00] ($250 after Feb 17)">Friday and Saturday [$225.00] ($250 after Feb 17)</option>
    <option value="Friday Only [$125.00] ($135 after Feb 17)">Friday Only [$125.00] ($135 after Feb 17)</option>
    <option value="Saturday Only [$125.00] ($135 after Feb 17)">Saturday Only [$125.00] ($135 after Feb 17)</option>
</select>
```

What I need to do is:

1. When user clicks the #promoupdate button, jQuery checks to see if #promocode value equals "PC123" or "PC321".
2. If it does, then #Amount should be reduced by (#CAT_Custom_358914 + 1) * $100
3. If it doesn't, then alert("That's not a valid promo code")

Keep in mind that the user can make changes to #CAT_Custom_358914 after submitting a promo code, so the promo code discount should update whenever that happens. I'm just a jQuery hack and my current progress wouldn't really address changes to #CAT_Custom_358914...

```
$("#promoupdate").click(function(){
    if($("#promocode").value()=="PC123") {
        [modify #Amount]
    };
    elseif($("#promocode").value()=="PC321") {
        [modify #Amount]
    };
    else($("#promocode").value()=="[anything else]") {
        alert("That's not a valid promo code");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/69Rd6/)

JS

```
var promocode;
var numberatt;
var pricing;
var total;
var finalprice;

$('#update').click(function(){
  promocode = $('#promocode').val();
  numberatt = $('#numberatt').val();
  pricing = $('#pricing').val();
  finalprice = numberatt * pricing;
    if (  (promocode == 'PC321') || (promocode == 'PC123') )
     {
       finalprice = +finalprice * 0.9;
      }
      else if ( promocode.length < 1)
        { 
         finalprice = +finalprice * 1;
         }
          else
           {
            alert("Invalid Promo Code");
            finalprice = 0;
            }
  $('.totaldiv').html( '$' + finalprice );
});
```

Comment: I know I'm asking for a pretty big solution here and I'm trying to figure out how to modify your Fiddle to make it work... I'm just not that strong on JS. My current calculator totals up fees when the Price/Option select fields are changed (it doesn't rely on the "Update" button), so I need this to work the same way. Most people won't have a promo code, so I only want them to have to click "update" if they enter a promo code.

Comment: I can probably write the math of my #CAT_custom field + 1, as opposed to having people choose the number of attendees from a separate numberatt field.

If you can modify to match that, great. But I appreciate your input so far and -- again -- I know this is a big one.

Comment: Ok, give this a try- I just made a function that is called with all three changes in the input fields - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/69Rd6/2/

Comment: You can automatically add one person by just adding a line before the "numberatt = $('..." - numberatt = numberatt + 1;